# Mapbox GL JS custom cursor

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Is there a simple way to have a custom cursor for a map? The following code I have works very nicely, it's simple too but it's just a predefined option :

```
map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'default';
```

Is it possible to have something like this? :

```
map.getCanvas().style.cursor = url('custom.png');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the style of the cursor through the css of the mapboxgl canvas container :

```
.mapboxgl-canvas-container { cursor: url(/path/to/cursor.png), auto !important }
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/dpbx96of/ ]

Comment: This does not work, the code does nothing either using a local or online PNG, and I know the path is correct. I have 4 maps on my page, the one I want it to work with is named "topleftmap" instead of "map". How would this work?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by converting the icon to a `.cur` file; [cursor.cc](https://www.cursor.cc/) is what I used.

I found that `.png` will not work, but `.cur` will; then, stdob--'s solution will work:

```
.mapboxgl-canvas-container { cursor: url(/path/to/cursor.CUR), auto !important }
```